# Get labels values dynamic by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

here is my code :

```
<div class="values"><span>Labels :</span></div>
<div id='main'>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="values">
            <div>
                <p><label>a</label><input type="checkbox" value="1"/></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p><label>b</label><input type="checkbox" value="2"/></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p><label>c</label><input type="checkbox" value="3"/></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="values">
            <div>
                <p><label>d</label><input type="checkbox" value="1"/></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p><label>e</label><input type="checkbox" value="2"/></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p><label>f</label><input type="checkbox" value="3"/></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Labels and input are generated dynamic. And i wannt do display the value/s of label seperated by comma in div `.values` for all checked input. And hide display when input check/uncheck.

http://jsfiddle.net/2gy67/4/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").click(function () {
    var values = $("input label").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(',');
    $('.values ').text(values)
     console.log(values);
 });
 updateTitle(values);
    });
```

Someone could help me to get this work ? ...

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
$("input label").map(function () {
```

to this:

```
$(":checked").siblings('lable').map(function () {
```

---

And delegate the event to the closest static parent and event should be `change`:

```
 $(document).on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
```

#### Note:

You have posted a wrong fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

You need event delegation for dynamically added elements.

```
 $(document).on('click','input[type=checkbox]:checked',function () {
     var values = $('input:checked').siblings('label').map(function () {
     return $(this).text();
 }).get().join(',');
 $('.values ').text(values)
 console.log(values);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="values"><span>Labels :</span><span class="selected"></span>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#main input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var selected = $('#main input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').map(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).prev().text());
        }).get();
        $('.values .selected').text(selected.join(', '))
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2gy67/)

Answer (score 0):

@ Arun P Johny thanks, code works great. But on my php site when i have input and label in parent div when i check checkbox i have only blank space and comma.

Something like this :

```
<div class="values"><span>Labels :</span><span class="selected"></span>
</div>
<div id='main'>
    <p>
    <label>f</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
    </p>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="values">
            <div>
                <p>
                <label>a</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                <label>b</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                <label>c</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="values">
            <div>
                <p>
                <label>d</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                <label>e</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
    <label>h</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
    </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#main input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var selected = $('#main input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').map(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).prev().text());
        }).get();
        $('.values .selected').text(selected.join(', '))
    })
})
```

Fiddle : [click](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaYY2/)

And in html it works fine but when input is check labels dipslay's fine a,b,c,d  and when put the code into my php site  i have blank spaces seperated by commna ,,,

And how to change jquery trigger, when i refresh page with code in $(document).ready(function() { }); , i lost the values. How to keep the label values after refresh the page ?